# Grouping Check box to allow one at the time

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I tried using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qbuttongroup.html but I couldn't find documentation of how to use it in this format

```
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox"  name="header">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Header</string>
        </property>
      </widget>
      </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QCheckBox"  name="matrix">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Matrix</string>
      </property>
    </widget>
  </item>
```

Comment: That class can not be used in Qt Designer, you have to apply it programmatically

Comment: Do you know what kind of syntax is that as I couldn't in qt documentation ? @eyllanesc

Comment: Do you mean the XML? That's part of Qt Designer

Comment: yes Makes Sense Thank you @eyllanesc